# Why JSON results not completed from nested related data using a EF models in .Net Core

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new in .net core, and I tried to get create a simple relation between two models with inverse, so my code was:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace doPayrollTestAuthAPI.Entities.Models
{
    public class Note
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("LookupForeignKey")]
        public Lookup LookupObj { get; set; }


    }




    public class Lookup
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name_FL { get; set; }
        public string Name_SL { get; set; }

        public string LookupCategory { get; set; }
        public string LookupType { get; set; }

        // static columns
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }


        [InverseProperty("LookupObj")]
        public List<Note> NotesObjects { get; set; }


    }    
}
```

and when I tried to retrieve notes with related data using the following code

```
var notes = await _context.Notes
    .Include(p => p.LookupObj)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

I got the following results:

```
[
{
    "id": "fc09fd08-95a0-487e-a28f-08d73b95eb94",
    "text": "the first note",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lookupObj": {
        "id": "9b7adbef-9322-4cd3-0e79-08d73b95eb97",
        "name_FL": "USD",
        "name_SL": "الدولار الامريكي",
        "lookupCategory": "Country",
        "lookupType": "System",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "usersWithBank": null,
        "usersWithSocialInsuranceOffice": null,
        "usersWithCountryOffice": null,
        "usersWithCurrency": null,
        "notesObjects": [
```

It seems that the data broken and json not complete

So is that valid that the inverse property selected here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `LookupForeignKey` is not correct. It should be `LookupId` based on your model. LookupForeignKey doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, it is caused by reference-loop, try to configure like below:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```